# Java - Loop through stack trace and get class and method instance?

Tags: java, annotations, stack-trace

I am trying to loop through the stack-trace and check to see if a specific annotation exists on any of those methods or not.
The following code initialized the correct class, but when I call getMethodName I get NoSuchMethodException. Any idea why it's throwing this exception?

```
StackTraceElement[] stackTraceElements = Thread.currentThread()
            .getStackTrace();

for (StackTraceElement element : stackTraceElements) {

    try {   
        Class<?> clazz = Class.forName(element.getClassName());
        Method method = element.getClass().getDeclaredMethod(element.getMethodName());
        cache = method.getAnnotation(Cache.class);
        break;
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: When calling getDeclaredMethod you need to provide the parameter types of the parameters for the desired method. You will also not get any inherited methods.

Comment: @BevynQ I don't want my logic to know anything about the method, other than the fact that it has this annotation. This annotation can be implemented anywhere in my web service layer, and I can't write code for every specific case

Comment: you could try `getMethods()` and `getDeclaredMethods()` they return a list of methods then you could do a name comparison. There is no way to differentiate between the methods that have the same name though.

Comment: @BevynQ I ended up going with your solution, and throwing an exception/warning when a method overload is found. Submit an answer so that I can accept. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Calling `getMethod` or `getDeclaredMethod` requires matching parameter types to return a result. You can use `getMethods` or `getDeclaredMethods` and do a method name comparison.

The downside with this is that

```
public void a()
```

and

```
public void a(int i)
```

will both yield matches if you are looking for method `a`.

```
public void dumpTrace(){
    StackTraceElement[] stackTraceElements = Thread.currentThread()
        .getStackTrace();

    for (StackTraceElement element : stackTraceElements) {

        try {
            Class<?> clazz = Class.forName(element.getClassName());
            System.out.println("Looking for " + element.getMethodName() + " in class " + clazz);
            for (Method method : clazz.getMethods()){
                if(method.getName().equals(element.getMethodName())){
                    System.out.println("Possible match : " + method);
                }
            }
            for (Method method : clazz.getDeclaredMethods()){
                if(method.getName().equals(element.getMethodName())){
                    System.out.println("Possible match : " + method);
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            //  oops do something here
        }
    }    
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Could be that you're calling getClass() on StackTraceElement which returns... StackTraceElement instead of the class of the execution point represented by the stack trace element.

StackTraceElement provides a getClassName() method you could use that one instead.